# Restringir input

Tags: javascript, html

una pregunta de que forma podria restringir el siguiente input para que solo admita números del 1 al 185?

```
<input type="text" name="purenpor" id="purenpor" maxlength="3">
```

el maxlength="3" lo agregue para que solo me permita agregar máximo 3 valores

Cualquier ayuda me seria de gran utilidad, muchas gracias.

Comment: Con PHP o JavaScript?

Comment: Hola BetaM, puede ser con cualquiera de las dos.

Comment: @BetaM ambas, para mas placer (?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los tags `<input>` tienen atributos `min` y `max` justo para esto. Si vas a usar un numero puedes cambiar tambien el tipo:

```
<input id="myInput" type="number" min="1" max="185" onchange=myFunction()>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input = document.getElementById("myInput")
  if (input.value > 185){
    input.value = 185
  } else if (input.value < 1) {
    input.value = 1
  }
}
</script>
```

*Edición:

Añade una función para el evento `onchange` que verifique el valor y lo cambie si está fuera del rango. Ten en cuenta que el evento se dispara una vez desenfocas el `input`.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. eso ya lo intente y efectivamente funciona si solo uso los selectores que me permite el input type number, el problema es que cuando lo escribo manualmente si me permite ingresar un nro mayor a 185.